# Popup calendar doesnt seem to popup on textbox focus

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I created a simple popup calendar and it won't seem to open on the focus of my textbox and I have no idea what the problem is:

```
<asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Start Date"></asp:Label> 
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>  
            <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" TargetControlID="txtStartDate" runat="server" />
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
```

Comment: See if some JS is being crashed on your page.

Comment: Why the ToolkitScriptManager placed in table cell?

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy Shouldn't it be?

Comment: @raheelkhokhar I haven't used any JS

Comment: I didn't mean that you used some JS. But lot of JS publishes when a .aspx page is rendered on browser, especially with AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added in the web.config file:

```
<add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
<add verb="GET" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler" validate="false"/>
```

Added System.Web.Extensions in my project references

Answer (score 0):

The code is good. No problems at all but, **It is advisable to put the ToolkitScriptManager just below the form tag.**
Also, I guess the problem is not with the code but with the reference of the toolkit added in your project.

**How to solve:**

1) Right click on your websiteName and choose **"Add reference"**. Browse to the path where your AjaxControlToolkit.dll is located and press ok.

2)If you have already set the reference in your project, **remove it and then re-add** the reference.

3) **Please make sure that the reference added in project has the same version of toolkit which is in your visual studio toolbox.** Otherwise It may lead to serious issues.